# How to visualize contact forces?

Tags: gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there anything in API that can visualize the contact forces from `contact` sensor? If not then how it can be implemented? Basically all I need is to show an axis similar to the ones used with joints.

Also, would it be possible to extend context menu with system GUI plugin to toggle such visualization?

Thanks in advance,

Boris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1441/how-to-visualize-contact-forces?/) by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-02-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Well I don't know if the code below can help you, but maybe serves as a start point to solve your question.

[myplugin.h](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1361495793768882.h)

[myplugin.cpp](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13614957791318271.cpp)

[contact.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13614959049239479.world)

The code is a proof of concept about using contact visuals passing by messages. Probably you should collect information about contact using the sensor and fill correctly the message fields.

You may enable "Contacts" in menu "View". I am using Gazebo 1.4 (compiled from source).

[image: Contact]

I hope that it helps you.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) with karma: 305 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-02-22**:
That's it. I keep forgetting about existence of main menu in Ubuntu. Thanks!